# Error in TesseractTransform in alfresco

Tags: transform, ocr, alfresco, tesseract, alfresco-share

I am tring to search content from image but unfortunately i got error. I am trying to use tesseract ocr tool. my service-context.xml code is as follow

```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC
> '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN'
> 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'> <!-- 
>     This file is part of the Tesseract Alfresco Integration written by
>     Simon White.    
> 
>     The Integration is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>     it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>     the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
>     (at your option) any later version.
> 
>     The Integration is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
>     but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>     MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
>     GNU General Public License for more details.
> 
>     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>     along with the Integration.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.   --> <beans>    <bean
> id="transformer.Tesseract"
>       class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer"
>       parent="baseContentTransformer">        <property name="worker">            <ref
> bean="transformer.worker.Tesseract" />        </property>         <property
> name="explicitTransformations">           <list>
>               <bean
>                   class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
>                   <property name="sourceMimetype">
>                       <value>image/png</value>
>                   </property>
>                   <property name="targetMimetype">
>                       <value>text/plain</value>
>                   </property>
>               </bean>
>               <bean
>                   class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
>                   <property name="sourceMimetype">
>                       <value>image/jpeg</value>
>                   </property>
>                   <property name="targetMimetype">
>                       <value>text/plain</value>
>                   </property>
>               </bean>
>               <bean
>                   class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
>                   <property name="sourceMimetype">
>                       <value>image/gif</value>
>                   </property>
>                   <property name="targetMimetype">
>                       <value>text/plain</value>
>                   </property>
>               </bean>             </list>         </property>     </bean>
> 
> 
>   <bean id="transformer.worker.Tesseract"
> class="smwc.alfresco.ocr.TesseractTransformWorker">       <property
> name="mimetypeService">           <ref bean="mimetypeService" />
>       </property>         <property name="executer">          <bean
> name="transformer.Tesseract.Command"
> class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec">
>               <property name="commandsAndArguments">
>                   <map>
>                       <entry key=".*">
>                           <list>
>                               <value>/home/alfresco-4.2.f-3/ocr.sh</value>
>                               <value>${source}</value>
>                               <value>${target}</value>
>                           </list>
>                       </entry>
>                   </map>
>               </property>             </bean>         </property>         <property name="checkCommand">          <bean
> name="transformer.Tesseract.CheckCommand"
> class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec">
>               <property name="commandsAndArguments">
>                   <map>
>                       <entry key=".*">
>                           <list>
>                               <value>/home/alfresco-4.2.f-3/ocr.sh</value>
>                               <value>-v</value>
>                           </list>
>                       </entry>
>                   </map>
>               </property>             </bean>         </property>     </bean>
> 
> </beans>
```

and ocr.sh as follows

```
#Number of Parameters
PARAM=$#
#Test parameters
if [[ $PARAM -lt 2 ]];
then
echo “Usage: $0 out.pdf input*.png”
echo “out.pdf is the desired output file”
echo “input*.png or input*.tif is a list of files to be converted”
exit 1
fi
#Outputfile
OUTFILE=$1
shift
#PDF output?
ATEST=$(basename $OUTFILE)
BTEST=$(basename $ATEST .pdf)
if [[ ${OUTFILE: -4} != ".pdf" ]]
then
echo “FILE $OUTFILE is not a pdf-file.”
exit 1
fi

#Do not overwrite existing output files
if [ -e $OUTFILE ]; then
echo “File $OUTFILE exists – not overwritten.”
exit 3
fi
LIST=
#Convert input files
for (( I=1; $I < $PARAM; I++ ))do
FILE=$1
shift
echo "Working on: $FILE"
#Convert
# /home/user/tesseract-ocr/api/tesseract $FILE $BTEST nobatch hocr
tesseract $FILE $BTEST$I -l en hocr
/usr/bin/hocr2pdf -i $FILE -o $I.pdf < $BTEST$I.html
#Eingangsliste der PDFS anlegen
LIST="$LIST$I.pdf "
done

#Concatination
echo "Concatenating PDF as $OUTFILE"
/usr/bin/pdftk $LIST output $OUTFILE

#cleaning up
echo "Cleaning up"
rm *html
for (( J=1;J<PARAM;J++ ))do
rm $J.pdf
done
echo "Finished."
```

problem is when i restart my alfresco server and upload any png image at that i got following error

```
Execution result: 
   os:         Linux
   command:    /home/alfresco-4.2.f-3/ocr.sh /home/alfresco-4.2.f-3/apache-tomcat/temp/Alfresco/TesseractTransformWorker_source_8694251634210177054.png /home/alfresco-4.2.f-3/apache-tomcat/temp/Alfresco/TesseractTransformWorker_target_1748466871282546000.txt
   succeeded:  false
   exit code:  2
   out:        
   err:        Cannot run program "/home/alfresco-4.2.f-3/ocr.sh": error=13, Permission denied
    at smwc.alfresco.ocr.TesseractTransformWorker.transform(TesseractTransformWorker.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer.transformInternal(ProxyContentTransformer.java:98)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:211)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.indexProperty(ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java:1509)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.createDocumentsImpl(ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java:907)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.createDocuments(ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java:726)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.ADMLuceneIndexerImpl$6.execute(ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java:2247)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.ADMLuceneIndexerImpl$6.execute(ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java:2243)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl$1.execute(AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.java:682)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.doInReadthroughTransaction(AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.java:667)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.readDocuments(ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java:2242)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.updateFullTextSearch(ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java:2180)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.fts.FullTextSearchIndexerImpl$1.execute(FullTextSearchIndexerImpl.java:232)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.fts.FullTextSearchIndexerImpl$1.execute(FullTextSearchIndexerImpl.java:220)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:342)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.fts.FullTextSearchIndexerImpl.index(FullTextSearchIndexerImpl.java:218)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.fts.FTSIndexerJob.execute(FTSIndexerJob.java:46)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

please help  me to solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: Did you ensure that the user that Alfresco runs as has permission to run the `ocr.sh` command? Only it looks from the error like they don't...

Comment: yes, Thanks for your reply..by the way i solved this problem but i have another problem please help..Problem is when i upload any image that image is converted into txt file if i upload any image in which contents are stored in table and with some formatting at that time that image is not converted in txt file properly. I got some garbage character in txt file.I want those contents are properly stored in txt file...How can i solve this problem?